# "Subquery returned more than 1 value" on SQLCLR Assembly

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-assembly

I have a SQLCLR assembly which creates a Telnet interface with a barcode scanner, and places anything it receives in a table. Occasionally, it crashes with the error:

```
Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine
or aggregate "fnBarcodeScanner":  

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Subquery returned more than 1 value.
This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, , >= or 
when the subquery is used as an expression.  

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:      
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(
       SqlException exception, Boolean  breakConnection)     
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(
       SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)     
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi.EventSink.DispatchMessages(
       Boolean ignoreNonFatalMessages)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SmiEventSink_Default.DispatchMessages(
       Boolean ignoreNonFatalMessages)     
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQuerySmi(
       Boolean sendToPipe)     
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(
       DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)     
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()     
  at MinimalisticTelnet.Program.Connect(String ip)  .

[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 6522)  The statement has been terminated.
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 3621).  The step failed.
```

I understand what the error means, but I'm not sure how it is being caused in this case. The only SQL in the assembly is an insert statement, which inserts a string into the table. There shouldn't be any way to have more than one value. Here is the C# code for the assembly (includes omitted for brevity):

```
namespace MinimalisticTelnet
{
    public class Program
    {
        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }

        public static void Connect(String ip)
        {
            String lastCode = null;
            TelnetConnection tc = new TelnetConnection(ip, 23);

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
            {
                SqlCommand InsertID = new SqlCommand();
                InsertID.Connection = conn;
                SqlParameter IDCodeParam = new SqlParameter("@Barcode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                conn.Open();
                while (tc.IsConnected)
                {
                    String barcode = tc.Read();
                    if (!((barcode).Length == 0))
                    {
                        barcode = barcode.Substring(0,barcode.IndexOf("\n") - 1);
                        if (!(barcode == lastCode))
                        {
                            lastCode = barcode;
                            SqlString sqlBarcode = barcode;
                            IDCodeParam.Value = sqlBarcode;
                            InsertID.Parameters.Add(IDCodeParam);
                            InsertID.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Barcode (Barcode)" +
                                " Values(@Barcode)";
                            InsertID.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            InsertID.Parameters.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for fnBarcodeScanner:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[fnBarcodeScanner]
        @ip [nvarchar](20)
    WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
    AS
    EXTERNAL NAME [Telnet].[MinimalisticTelnet.Program].[Connect]
    GO
```

And here is the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Barcode]
ON [dbo].[tbl_Barcode]
AFTER INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @MVID        INT,
              @P           VARCHAR(25),
              @NewLane     VARCHAR(10),
              @TC          INT,
              @DID         INT,
              @AD          DATE,
              @AT          VARCHAR(18),
              @TrayCount   INT,
              @DivertCount INT,
              @ScanID      VARCHAR(50),
              @PID         INT,
              @cDivert     VARCHAR(8)

      SET @ScanID = (SELECT Barcode
                     FROM   tbl_Barcode)--Barcode Value
      SET @MVID = (SELECT MVID
                   FROM   tbl_Divert
                   WHERE  Barcode = @ScanID)--JOT Version ID
      SET @P = (SELECT PalletNbr
                FROM   tbl_Divert
                WHERE  Barcode = @ScanID)--Pallet Number
      SET @PID = (SELECT PalletID
                  FROM   tbl_Pallet_Verification
                         INNER JOIN tbl_Pallet_Mailing
                           ON tbl_Pallet_Verification.MailingID = tbl_Pallet_Mailing.MailingID
                  WHERE  tbl_Pallet_Mailing.MVID = @MVID
                         AND tbl_Pallet_Verification.PalletNum = @P)--PAT Pallet ID
      SET @AD = ( Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Getdate(), 110) AS DATE) )--Today's Date
      SET @AT = CONVERT(TIME, Getdate())--Current Time
      SET @cDivert = (SELECT Divert
                      FROM   tbl_Divert
                      WHERE  Barcode = @ScanID)
      SET @NewLane = (SELECT TOP 1 ID
                      FROM   tbl_Tray_Lanes
                      WHERE  LaneActive = -1
                             AND ID NOT IN(SELECT Divert
                                           FROM   tbl_Pallet_Lanes
                                           WHERE  DateCompleted IS NULL))--Find Open Lane
      SET @TC = (SELECT Count(TrackerID)
                 FROM   tbl_Divert
                 WHERE  MVID = @MVID
                        AND PalletNbr = @P)--Tray Count
      SET @TrayCount = (SELECT Count(TrackerID)
                        FROM   tbl_Divert
                        WHERE  Barcode = @ScanID)--Is Tray Found in Divert Table
      SET @DivertCount = (SELECT Count(TrackerID)
                          FROM   tbl_Divert
                          WHERE  Barcode = @ScanID
                                 AND Divert IS NOT NULL)--Verify Tray has not been scanned

      --Add Date/Time to Tray Record.  This will mark tray as scanned
      SELECT TrackerID
      FROM   tbl_Divert
      WHERE  Barcode = @ScanID
             AND Divert IS NULL

      IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            IF @NewLane IS NOT NULL
              BEGIN --Add Available lane to Lane Table and give tray record the LaneID
                  IF @TrayCount > 0 --Verify tray record exist
                    BEGIN
                        --IF @DivertCount = 0 --If not previously scanned
                        --Begin--Insert Lane Record
                        INSERT INTO tbl_Pallet_Lanes
                                    (MVID,
                                     PalletID,
                                     PalletNbr,
                                     Divert,
                                     TrayCount,
                                     DateStarted,
                                     TimeStarted)
                        SELECT @MVID,
                               @PID,
                               @P,
                               @NewLane,
                               @TC,
                               @AD,
                               @AT

                        --Get LaneID
                        SET @DID = (SELECT ID
                                    FROM   tbl_Pallet_Lanes
                                    WHERE  MVID = @MVID
                                           AND PalletNBR = @P)

                        --Add LaneID to tray record
                        UPDATE tbl_Divert
                        SET    Divert = @NewLane,
                               DivertID = @DID
                        WHERE  MVID = @MVID
                               AND PalletNbr = @P
                    --END
                    END
              END

            IF @NewLane IS NULL
              BEGIN --If there is no open lane assign Lane 16.  This will send the tray to end of tray tracker for 
                  --manual pallet load.
                  UPDATE tbl_Divert
                  SET    Divert = 16,
                         DivertID = 0
                  WHERE  MVID = @MVID
                         AND Barcode = @ScanID
              END
        END

      DELETE FROM tbl_Barcode --Clear barcode table

      UPDATE tbl_Divert
      SET    Scanned = @AD,
             ScanStatus = 1 --Scan Status Flags which Reader 
      WHERE  Barcode = @ScanID
  END
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on `tbl_Barcode` that was designed to only handle one row at a time?

Comment: Just for cleanup: you should have a USING clause on the SqlCommand as well; and you can get rid of the conn.Close() call.  The Using on the SqlConnection will do that for you.

Comment: Are any referential integrity queries being executed automatically that could cause this? Have you tried looking at a SQL trace using query analyzer? Sometimes more queries are executed than you expect.

Comment: @user92546 I believe so, yes. But there should never be more than one row in it.

Comment: @SaintWacko That doesn't mean the trigger doesn't try to manipulate multiple rows via another query even though the original insert was a single row.

Comment: @shawnt00 I meant tbl_Barcode will never have more than one row in it. The trigger deletes the row as soon as it runs.

Comment: @ChrisLively Can you show me what you mean? I'm still somewhat new to SQL Server and C#.

Comment: Triggers operate on rowsets.  A trigger that is written on the assumption that only one row will change at a time is an accident waiting to happen.  Typically it starts with something like `declare @FooId as Int; select @FooId = FooId from inserted -- Bang!; ...`.

Comment: @user92546 And that will cause it to only select what has just been inserted, regardless of how many rows are in the table?

Comment: The [`inserted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) table contains only the rows that caused the `insert` (or `update`) trigger to fire.  It may be one or more rows.  (There is a corresponding `deleted` table used for `update` and `delete` triggers.)  At worst you can create a `cursor` and waddle through it.  Typically it is used in rowset operations, e.g. to perform complex validation between columns and/or other tables.

Comment: @user92546 - In this case though we can see their insert statement is only inserting one row. I suspect trigger too but we need to see it.

Comment: It sounds like the function can return multiple rows in some combination of arguments that wasn't expected. You should probably focus on isolating that.

Comment: I've added the code for the trigger, but if it was the trigger, wouldn't the error identify that as the culprit, instead of the sproc calling the assembly?

Comment: @MartinSmith Now how did you do that?

Comment: Could be any one of the `SET @ScanID,@MVID,@P,@PID,@cDivert ...` statements. Do you mean the formatting? [I have the desktop version of this formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)

Comment: @MartinSmith Is there any way for me to debug it so I can step through and see where it crashes?

Comment: @SaintWacko - It will probably be the statement `SET @ScanID = (SELECT Barcode FROM   tbl_Barcode)` as you are assuming the table only has one row but this is the same table you just inserted to. Selecting from `tbl_Barcode` will include that new row too.

Comment: @MartinSmith But tbl_Barcode was empty before I inserted the new row.

Comment: In that case you could temporarily insert `TOP 1` into all the `SELECT`s that get assigned to scalar variables until you find the culprit.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah, there's an idea! Problem is, it could take awhile, as it usually only crashes once or twice a day. I wish the error log would say what actually caused the problem, instead of just giving a general idea of what was going on at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is throwing an exception.  That is causing SQL Server to think you are returning multiple values back from the function.

You will probably want to know exactly what values are being passed to your insert statement (as in the full list).  I'd be curious to see if you have any key collision issues.

The line you are using to not insert the same barcode as the previous one seems like you are trying to avoid something like that.

Comment: Yes, I understand the error, I'm trying to figure out how my code could cause that error.

Comment: @SaintWacko: I think you're misunderstanding.  The code is throwing *an* exception; however, the one it is throwing is being overwhelmed by the one you are seeing.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see what you're saying. Is there any way for me to figure out what the real exception is?

Comment: @SaintWacko: The only recommendation I can make is that your SQLCLR code needs to be littered with try .. catches and actually log everything it is doing to a file.  Let that run for a bit and you'll figure it out.